# Is there a consistent, unsound, $\omega$-inconsistent, effective theory that doesn't prove its own inconsistency?

Tags: lo.logic

Can we have a consistent and effective (fulfilling Godel's criteria) first order theory $T$, that is both arithmetically unsound and $\omega$-inconsistent, and yet doesn't prove its own inconsistency ( i.e. $T \not \vdash \neg \operatorname {Con}(T)$)?

Comment: "*both* unsound and $\omega$-inconsistent"? Isn't that redundant? What would be an example of a theory that's sound and $\omega$-inconsistent? Maybe I don't understand what "unsound" means (or what $\omega$-inconsistent means), I'm not a logician.

Comment: @bof, Not it is not redundant. See: [$\omega$-consistent theory](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A9-consistent_theory)

Comment: If the theory is expressed in the language of arithmetic, then it is redundant. An $\omega$-inconsistent theory proves every instance $\varphi(n)$ of some formula, but also $\neg\forall x\ \varphi(x)$. This violates soundness, since either some $\varphi(n)$ is not actually true or the universal is true.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins, so is arithmetically sound and being $\omega$-consistent equivalent if the theory is expressed in the language of arithmetic?

Comment: No, because the theory $\text{PA}+\neg\omega\text{-Con}(\text{PA})$ in your link is unsound but $\omega$-consistent.

Comment: @Joel David Hamkins, so, is every arithmetically sound theory an arithmetically $\omega$-consistent theory? Where the latter is $\omega$-consistency for arithmetic properties.

Comment: Yes, because the truth is $\omega$-consistent. This is the same issue we discussed recently on your other question.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins, True! But, unlike what was presented in the other question, here we can apply that to theories that are not necessarily true nor are necessarily written in the language of arithmetic! So, $T$ whether true or not, whether written in the language of arithmetic or not, once it's arithmetically sound then it is arithmetically $\omega$-consistent. This is a broader result.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sure. Consider something like $T=\mathsf{PA}+\neg\mathit{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC})$ (assuming $\mathsf{ZFC}$ is actually consistent of course).

- $T$ is consistent but not $\omega$-consistent (it proves that each specific natural number fails to be a $\mathsf{ZFC}$-proof of $\perp$, but still proves that some number is a $\mathsf{ZFC}$-proof of $\perp$).
- More interestingly, $T\not\vdash\neg \mathit{Con}(T)$. To see this, note that if it did we would have $\mathsf{PA}$-provably that $\neg\mathit{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC})\rightarrow\neg\mathit{Con}(T)$. Taking the contrapositive and shifting to the stronger theory $\mathsf{ZFC}$, we would get $$\mathsf{ZFC}\vdash\mathit{Con}(T)\rightarrow\mathit{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC}),$$ a contradiction since $\mathsf{ZFC}$ already proves the consistency of $T$. (Why does $\mathsf{ZFC}$ prove the consistency of $T$? If $T$ were inconsistent then $\mathsf{PA}$ would prove $\mathit{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC})$ and hence be inconsistent. So since $\mathsf{ZFC}$ proves that $\mathsf{PA}$ is consistent, $\mathsf{ZFC}$ also proves that $T$ is consistent.)

Comment: If you replace $ZFC$ with $PA+Con(PA)$ everywhere, then you can greatly weaken your consistency/soundness assumptions.

Comment: I'm still not following your argument.  Try the following.  Replace $ZFC$ everywhere with $ZFC':=PA+Con(PA)+\neg Con(PA+Con(PA))$, and let $T'=PA+\neg Con(ZFC')$.  Your same argument seems to apply.

Comment: @PaceNielsen I'm not sure I see the problem - it doesn't look to me like your $T'$ *does* prove its own inconsistency. Your $T'$ thinks that $\mathsf{ZFC}'\vdash\perp$, which is to say (via the deduction theorem) that $$\mathsf{PA}+Con(\mathsf{PA})\vdash Con(\mathsf{PA}+Con(\mathsf{PA})).$$ Consequently, your $T'$ thinks that $\mathsf{PA}+Con(\mathsf{PA})$ is inconsistent by the (internalized) second incompleteness theorem. But so? $T'$ doesn't literally contain that theory, it only contains $\mathsf{PA}$. (cont'd)

Comment: And if we replace your $T'$ with $\mathsf{ZFC}'+\neg Con(\mathsf{ZFC}')$ - call the result $T''$ - then we lose the analogue of the step in my argument where $\mathsf{ZFC}\vdash Con(T)$: it is not the case that $\mathsf{ZFC}'$ proves the consistency of $T''$. So I think you've just found another (much more parsimonious but slightly trickier to check) instance of a pair of theories to which my argument applies.

Comment: My question is regarding your last sentence.  I don't see how $ZFC$ proving $Con(PA)$ implies that it also proves $Con(T)$.  My use of $ZFC'$ and $T'$ was only meant to peel away a lot of irrelevancies.  I don't understand how $ZFC'\vdash Con(PA)$ would imply $ZFC'\vdash Con(T')$.

Comment: @PaceNielsen That's what the sentence before it explains, which I'll expand on a bit here for readability: reasoning in $\mathsf{ZFC}$, the only way that $\mathsf{PA}+\neg Con(\mathsf{ZFC})$ could be inconsistent is if $\mathsf{PA}\vdash Con(\mathsf{ZFC})$. But that would a fortiori imply $\mathsf{PA}\vdash Con(\mathsf{PA})$, hence $\mathsf{PA}$ is inconsistent - which $\mathsf{ZFC}$ knows isn't the case.

Comment: I think my question boils down to what "reasoning in $ZFC$" means, in this context. For my purposes, let's use $ZFC'$ instead.  What does it mean to "reason in $ZFC'$"?  For example, $ZFC'$ thinks of itself as inconsistent, so should we take it for granted that $1=0$, since we are reasoning in $ZFC'$?

Comment: @PaceNielsen No. $\mathsf{ZFC}'$ does **not** believe that $\perp$ (or $0=1$) is true; it **does** believe that $\mathsf{ZFC}'\vdash\perp$ is true. More precisely (but conflating meta-level sentences with their arithmetizations for simplicity), we have $$\mathsf{ZFC}'\not\vdash\perp\quad\mbox{but}\quad \mathsf{ZFC}'\vdash (\mathsf{ZFC}'\vdash\perp)$$ "Reasoning in $[X]$" just means "everything that follows is provable in $[X]$."

Comment: Incidentally, this is exactly why I phrased my answer with $\mathsf{PA}$ and $\mathsf{ZFC}$; optimizing for system-strength forces us to reason inside theories that prove their own inconsistency, and that's often a stumbling block.

Comment: Thanks, that clarifies things.  If I'm understanding correctly, we just need a theory strong enough where Godel's 2nd incompleteness theorem can be internalized.  So we could take $T=Q + \neg Con (Q+Con(Q))$, where $Q$ is Robinson arithmetic.  (And note, neither $PA+Con(PA)$ nor $Q+Con(Q)$ proves its own inconsistency, so optimizing for system-strength doesn't lead us to a bad place.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber, is there an example where $T$ is not formalized in the language of arithmetic?

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar Sure, use $\mathsf{KP}+\neg Con(\mathsf{ZFC})$ instead, where $Con$ is phrased set-theoretically instead of arithmetically.

Answer (score 1):

Noah's answer may be the best here. But I'll add this as an additional answer. In particular, the theory in question is not fully formalized in the language of arithmetic.

Let's take theory $\sf PA + \neg \, \omega$-$\sf \operatorname{Con}(PA)$, this is an arithmetically unsound $\omega$-consistent arithmetic theory. Now, to break $\omega$-consistency we can add a primitive constant $c$ to it's language, then add the schema: $$ [\mathcal S_n(0) < c]_{n=0,1,2,..}$$
Where $ \mathcal S_n(0)$ denotes the $n$-iterated successor of $0$, where of course $n$ being concrete natural. This would break $\omega$-consistency at $c$ for the property $(x < c)$.

So, this theory is both arithmetically unsound and $\omega$-inconsistent.

Now, the base theory $\sf PA + \neg \, \omega$-$\sf \operatorname{Con}(PA)$, being $\omega$-consistent, cannot prove its own inconsistency, and since the above theory is obtained through compactness from the base theory then it cannot prove a sentence in the language of the base theory that the base theory itself cannot prove. Hence, $T \not \vdash \neg \operatorname{Con}(T)$.